# Escape Keyboard event not firing while dragging

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a drag event stop when the mouse enters a specific zone. I could not make it work with trying to simulate a mouseup event so I thought I can simulate pressing the escape key to stop the drag event. The simEscape function is starting but it's not simulating the key stroke.
Any idea why ?

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
         #boxA, #boxB {
            float:left;padding:10px;margin:10px;-moz-user-select:none;
         }
         #boxA { background-color: #6633FF; width:75px; height:75px;  }
         #boxB { background-color: #FF6699; width:150px; height:150px; }
      </style>
       
       </head>
   <body>
      <center>
        <div id = "main">
         <h2>cancel drag test</h2>
         <div id="boxA" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)">
            <p>Drag Me</p>
         </div>
         <div id="boxB" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondrop="return dragDrop(event)" >Stop Dragging here</div>
        </div>   
      </center>
   </body>
   <script>
    function dragStart(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
    ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target,0,0);
    return true;
  }
 function dragEnter(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    simEscape();
    return true;
 }
 function dragOver(ev) {
    return false;
 }
 function dragDrop(ev) {
    var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
    ev.stopPropagation();
    return false;
 }

function simEscape(){
 console.log("SimEscapedStarted"); // confirm the function starts
   
 const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    isTrusted: true,
    charCode: 0,
    key: "Escape",
    code: "Escape",
    which: 27,
    keyCode: 27,
  });
  
  document.getElementById('boxA').dispatchEvent(event);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: It is firing when I run the code snippet here in stackoverflow

Comment: When I run the snippet here it fires the "simEscape" function but not the dispatchEvent or at least it does not release the drag like it would do when you press the esc key.

Answer (score 1):

Based on testing, it appears that drag and drop events are either handled by the operating system and not sent to the browser, or handled by the browser and not sent to the page code.

If you log keyboard and mouse events to the console using:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown",  (e)=>{console.log(e)});
document.addEventListener("mouseup",  (e)=>{console.log(e)});
document.addEventListener("mousedown",(e)=>{console.log(e)});
```

You'll notice the following (in Chrome):

- If you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> while selecting text, all three events fire.
- If you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> while dragging an element (link, image), the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events fire, but the <kbd>Esc</kbd> event does not.
- If you move the "Drag Me" box in your example (regardless of whether you press Escape), none of the events fire.

This tells me that key events simulated by the page will not affect a drag and drop operation.